# `my 'return' keyword seems not to be working in visual studio code while writing javascript..any help will be appriciated `

Tags: javascript

i have been writting javascript on visual studio code and the 'return keyword seems not to be working.the code is correct and should display sumOfCount on the console but instead it onlt displays 1..this is code for displaying the number of times an element appears in an array .

```
const numbers=[1,2,,2,3,4,5,1,];

const sumOfCount=countOccurence(numbers,2);
console.log (sumOfCount);

function countOccurence(array,searchElement){
    let count=0;
    for (let number of array)
        if (number===searchElement);
            count++;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `if (number===searchElement);` shouldn't have that semi-colon at the end. You should probably start putting `{}` in your code for your statements so you can identify these issues more quickly,

Answer (score -1):

hi remove semicolon from end of if statement.
please refer below code

```
const numbers=[1,2,,2,3,4,5,1,];
const sumOfCount=countOccurence(numbers,2);
console.log (sumOfCount);

function countOccurence(array,searchElement){
let count=0;
for (let number of array)
    if (number===searchElement)
        count++;
return count;
}
```

Comment: Please don't add answers to questions with code with simple typos when the option is to close the question.